# Convert Double to String with minimum fraction digits without using NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, string, format, numbers, double

Given these Doubles:

```swift
let one: Double = 1
let alsoOne: Double = 1.0
let oneAsWell: Double = 1.00
let x: Double = 1.10
let y: Double = 1.010
let z: Double = 1.0010
```

**How can I convert them to String so they keep only their relevant fraction digits without a NumberFormatter or a format (where one can only specify a fixed number of fraction digits)?**

Playground shows exactly what I want:

```
1
1
1
1.1
1.01
1.001
```

Using `String()`, `String(describing:)`, `.description` or `"\()"` gives me:

```
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.1
1.01
1.001
```

So what is Playground using for its string conversion? I want that! ;)

[This is what the Playground looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRGlA.png)

Comment: it is using the types description property. Check Swift protocol [CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)

Comment: Playground is probably using number formatter with minimum fraction digits set to zero. **"(where one can only specify a fixed number of fraction digits)"** This is not true as you can set the numberFormatter minimum and maximum fraction digits properties.

Comment: `.description` has the same result as all the other. The quoted part was referring to `format` only. I know NumberFormatter supports settings for fraction digits. Want to avoid it for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var string: String {
        let result = "\(self)"
        return result.hasSuffix(".0") ? String(result.dropLast(2)) : result
    }
}

let one: Double = 1
let alsoOne: Double = 1.0
let oneAsWell: Double = 1.00
let x: Double = 1.10
let y: Double = 1.010
let z: Double = 1.0010

print(one.string)        // 1
print(alsoOne.string)    // 1
print(oneAsWell.string)  // 1
print(x.string)          // 1.1
print(y.string)          // 1.01
print(z.string)          // 1.001
```

Comment: Why is there no `String`-initializer for `FloatingPoint`?